# Compositing file output node file slots keys length are limited in length

Tags: python, scripting

I was trying to setup some File Output node inputs through the Python API and I found this weird behavior:

```py
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene
node_tree = scene.node_tree
scene.use_nodes = True

file_output = node_tree.nodes.new("CompositorNodeOutputFile")

slot_name = "a" * 64 # Arbitrary string longer than 63 chars
slot = file_output.file_slots.new(slot_name)

# This would give an error:
# file_output.file_slots[slot_name]

assert slot.name == slot_name, f"Got {len(slot.name)} chars, expected {len(slot_name)}"
```

```
Error: Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Text", line 15, in <module>
AssertionError: Got 63 chars, expected 64
```

It seems that Blender is truncating the key length to 63 characters.

Is this a bug or a known behavior?

Comment: Yes, Blender names have 63 character length limit.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Thanks I just found other topics mentioning this limit online. The name has a 63 character limit but not the underlying data. For now I am doing `file_output_node.inputs[out_name[:63]]` as a workaround...

Comment: You never explained why you need long names, so I couldn't suggest any workaround. Might be an https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: You're right, in fact I am using a single File Output node to output separated EXR files to disk. I am using the file slot names to point to a different sub directory per AOV like `Combined_arbre/SH010_LGT_QUILL_v009_Combined_arbre.####.exr` (which is then added to the base path). Sometimes if the AOV name is too long (light groups `Combined_*`) it can overflow the 63 character length.

A solution could be to create a separated file output node per AOV (except for EXR multilayer)

Comment: You can set the path and you can even access the input by its full name, and you can maintain a dictionary translating the long names to the short names if needed.